# Create Button in Unity 4.6 from code

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine

How can I create a Button (Not GUI etc) in Unity 4.6 from code? I need to be able to specify the action when tapped.

I tried adding a delegate or something to `onClick` but I can't get it to work.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html

This is the code I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtontitleAndAction {
    public string Title;
    public delegate void Del();

    public ButtontitleAndAction(string title, Del theaction) {
        this.Title = title;
        this.action = theaction;
    }
    public void Call() {
        Debug.Log("Call " + this.Title);
        this.action();
    }

    private Del action;
}

public class MjalertScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text Text;
    public GameObject gameobjectButtons;
    public GameObject gameobjectMjalertbutton;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {

    }

    public void Addbuttons(ButtontitleAndAction[] buttontitles) {
        //  public void Addbuttons(string[] buttontitles) {
        GridLayoutGroup grid = this.gameobjectButtons.GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>();
        float newwidth = 400 / buttontitles.Length;
        grid.cellSize = new Vector2(newwidth, grid.cellSize.y);
        foreach (ButtontitleAndAction buttondata in buttontitles) {
            GameObject gameobjectButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(this.gameobjectMjalertbutton);
            Transform child = gameobjectButton.transform.GetChild(0); // There should just be one child, the gameobject for the Text label.
            Text textofbutton = child.gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
            textofbutton.text = buttondata.Title;
            gameobjectButton.transform.SetParent(gameobjectButtons.transform, false);
            Button buttonofbutton = gameobjectButton.GetComponent<Button>();
            Debug.Log("buttonofbutton: " + buttonofbutton + ", for label text: " + buttondata.Title);
            buttonofbutton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
                Debug.Log("DOO Something!");
                //buttondata.Call();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The buttons don't ever react to any taps. I'd expected "DOO Something!" something to be output but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above has no problems actually. I figured out the real problem. Somehow, an EventSystem item was never added to the hierarchy. Just add one and buttons will work. Actually in my case, neither buttons through code or using the editor ever worked. The lack of the EventSystem was the problem.